# Problem 11.15 in Romer in Advanced Macroeconomics 4 edition

Tags: macroeconomics

I'm a little bit confused about the answers proposed in the solutions manual to the problem 11.15:

*In the model of delegation analyzed in Section 11.7, suppose that the policymaker’s preferences are believed to be described by (11.59), with $a'> a$, when $\pi^e$ is determined. Is social welfare higher if these are actually the policymaker’s preferences, or if the policymaker’s preferences in fact match the social welfare function, (11.54)?*

Important information of the problem are the equations:

> 

$$L = \frac{1}{2}(y - y^*)^2 + \frac{1}{2}a(\pi\ - \pi^*)^2 \  ,\  \ \ y^* > \bar{y} \ , \ \ \ a>0. \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (11.54) $$

> 

$$\pi^e = \pi^* + \frac{b}{a}(y^* - \bar{y})\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (11.58) $$

> 

$$L' = \frac{1}{2}(y - y^*)^2 + \frac{1}{2}a'(\pi\ - \pi^*)^2 \  ,\  y^* > \bar{y} \ , \ a'>0. \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (11.59) $$

> 

**The answer proposed in the Solutions Manual**

*Expected inflation, $\pi^e$, is determined by the public's beliefs. So both the $" a' " $policymaker and the $"a"$ policymaker face the same $\pi^e$, since in either case, the public believes it is facing an $" a' "$ policymaker. Thus both policymakers have the same choice set. The "a" policymaker makes her choice to maximize true social welfare, whereas the $" a' "$ policymaker makes her choice to maximize something else. Thus social welfare must be higher with the $"a"$ policymaker.*

> 

**My point is: considering $\pi^e = \pi$ and the fact that $a'>a$, which implies in $\frac{b}{a'} < \frac{b}{a}$, shouldn't the correct answer be the social welfare is higher with the $"a' "$ policymaker?

> 

**Reference:**
Romer, David.
Advanced macroeconomics / David Romer. — 4th ed. (chapter 11)